# Can't post data to Heroku server using ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, heroku

I'm new on `nodejs`. My problem is: I deployed my app to heroku. When I post the request to heroku server, it errors that 404 (not Found)

**Here is my ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://translate-extension.herokuapp.com/geta',
   type: "POST",
   data: "hello"
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

**And here is my nodejs code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT ||3000, () => {
  console.log('Connected!');
})
let request = require('request');
var token = 'api_key'
var imagesURL=[];
function getRandomImages() {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * (100 - 5)));
  request({
    url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/323925094473196/photos/`,
    qs: {
      fields: "images",
      limit: 5,
      offset: randomIndex,
      access_token: token
    },
    method: "GET"
  }, (error, res, body) => {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    var rs = JSON.parse(body);
    imagesURL = rs.data.map(data => data.images[0].source);
  })
};
app.get(`/`, (req, res)=>{
  res.send('Hello');
})
app.post('/geta', (req, res) => {
  console.log("i'm taked");
  getRandomImages();
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('Get imagesURL successful');
    res.send(imagesURL);
  },2000)
})
```

If my English is wrong, i'm sorry about that

I have learn so much.

Anyway thank for read my quetstion :)

Edit: I fixed it, but problem is Facebook api can't get publish stream with long lived access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your post URL with:

https://translate-extension.herokuapp.com/getA

It's working fine.

I think in your deployed code you have declared as `getA` not `geta`

Comment: my new problem is Facebook api can't get publish stream with long lived access token